# Dividing a large integer by 10 and truncating the decimal is not working in python

Tags: python, truncate

The following program runs into an error because when I divide the large integer by 10 and truncate it, Python does weird math and returns a different number.

```
# Program to add the digits in an integer
# eg. 463728 would equal 30 ( 4+6+3+7+2+8 )

the_sum = 2**1000

running_tot = 0
sum_length = len(str(the_sum)) # to calculate the length of the integer

i = 0 #initialize iterator

while i < sum_length:
    remainder = the_sum % 10     # Find out the last no. in int.
    running_tot += remainder     # adds the last no. to running total
    the_sum = int(the_sum / 10)  # truncates the last no. for original number
    i += 1                       # increment iterator 
 
print(running_tot)
```

I would like to know why Python does this?

Comment: Because you chose not to use integer division.

Comment: Probably because of floating point math errors

Comment: Use integer division: `the_sum = the_sum // 10`

Comment: Thanks all. Much appreciated.